# Ozeki Server not receiving SMS messages

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

I'm trying to get Ozeki to receive SMS messages from my GSM Nokia E63 - it will send messages fine but wont receive them. I am also trying to get a PHP/HTML form to generate messages, but the example on the Ozeki website won't work!

```
<?php
if ($submit=="Send")
{
$url='http://localhost:9333/ozeki?'; 
$url.="action=sendMessage";
$url.="&login=admin";
$url.="&password=abc123"; 
$url.="&recepient=".urlencode($recepient);
$url.="&messageData=".urlencode($message); 
$url.="&sender=".urlencode($sender);
file($url);
}
?> 
<html>
<form method=post action='index.php'> 
<table border=0>
<tr> 
<td>Sender</td><td><input type='text' name='sender'></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Recepient</td><td><input type='text' name='recepient'></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Message</td><td><input type='text' name='message'</td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td colspan=2><input type=submit name=submit value=Send> 
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</form> 
</html>
```

Any help?

Comment: Hi,Sam Thompson. did you finally find any solution to this. I mean I also tried the example given on the website to send sms using pHP but its not working for me either. But I can send sms using the web tool. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Ozeki supports GSM Nokia E63 or any newer nokia phone (for receiving).. Sending works fine

"If your phone model is based on the Symbian mobile phone operating system (most high end Nokia and SonyEricsson devices) you will not be able to use it for incoming SMS. Symbian phones never deliver incoming SMS messages and incoming delivery report to the modem interface of the phone."

Answer (score 1):

siemens c55 + bluetech cable data works fine..

Answer (score 1):

Just close the message input box .Maybe your container doesn't pick that. Just put:

```
<td><input type='text' name='message' /></td>
```

instead of

```
<td><input type='text' name='message'</td>
```