# Getting an Error Message when Sending SMS using using PHP

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

I have an sms server installed on my computer and a gsm modem attached to the usb port, so if I hit `http://localhost:9333/ozeki?` on the browser a login page appears and after I log in there is a form using which I can send sms to mobile phones. This works fine.

Now to send sms from my web application(which will be running on localhost)

I have created a form and it looks like following

```
<form name="form" action="send.php" method="post">

<table width="600" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Sender </td> <td> <input type="text" name="sender" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Recepient </td> <td> <input type="text" name="recepient" /> </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>Message </td> <td> <input type="text" name="message" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /> </td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

My send.php

```
   $recepient=$_POST['recepient'];
   $message=$_POST['message'];
   $sender=$_POST['sender'];

   $url='http://localhost:9333/ozeki?';
  $url.="action=sendMessage";
  $url.="&login=admin";
  $url.="&password=abc123";
  $url.="&recepient=".urlencode($recepient);
  $url.="&messageData=".urlencode($message);
  $url.="&sender=".urlencode($sender);
  file($url);
```

Now the problem is when I click on the submit button the page goes to send.php and usually it takes a lot of time to respond and when it finally does this error message appear:

Warning: file(http://localhost:9333/ozeki?action=sendMessage&login=admin&password=abc123&recepient={my_number}&messageData=comp&sender={my_number}) [function.file]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send.php on line 14

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send.php on line 16

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948893/ozeki-server-not-recieving-sms-messages

Comment: You said there is a log in page you have to log into first before you can send an SMS. Are you sure that appending the login and password is correct? Maybe there is a cookie that it expects you to be sending instead of the details in the request. What happens if you paste your `$url` into the browser (without logging in first).

Comment: @AndrewR thanks for your reply. If I paste the URL I mean this-> http://localhost:9333/ozeki? then the user login page appears. Thanks :)

Comment: And Yes I have checked the login and password.. they are both correct :)

Comment: What I meant was, what do you get when you paste the full URL `http://localhost:9333/ozeki?action=sendMessage&login=admin&password=abc123&recepient=01672095631&messageData=comp&sender=01719349818`  - Does it send your message?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I didn't understand you..However, I didn't check it before.. I pasted the link just now and have found this sendMessage<AcceptReport><StatusCode>0</StatusCode><StatusText>Message accepted for delivery</StatusText><Messageid>4454772</Messageid></AcceptReport>

Comment: If you don't mind would you please check this link.. they have a solution to this problem but this is not working for me at all. http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-82921.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of file().